# Only Start of Confirmed Built String Displays in Confirmation Popup Via Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller, string, popup

With each inputCheckbox on my VF page checked, I'm adding to a string in my controller:

```
public with sharing class ApplicationServerMonitorController {

    public String contactsAboutToEmail {get;set;}

    public ApplicationServerMonitorController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        contactsAboutToEmail = 'You are about to email:';
    }
}
```

The way I'm building it throughout the rest of the controller is quite complicated, but I assure you that it's successful.  After clicking the last checkbox and before clicking a command button, debug logs confirm that the string has been added too and includes all that's expected.

Now, when I ultimately click the command button, I want to display the final string in a confirmation dialog box.

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb" Rendered="{!IF(OR($Profile.Name = 'Support_Power_SvceConsole', $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator', $Profile.Name = 'SF Admin PFlint'),
                                          true,
                                          false)}">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Email Selected Customers">
        <apex:outputLabel value="Subject" style="font-weight:bold" for="sub"></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="sub" value="{!customerEmailSubject}" style="width: 550px"/>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Body" style="font-weight:bold" for="bod"></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputTextarea id="bod" value="{!customerEmailMessage}" style="width: 550px; height: 111px" required="false"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
        <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!SendEmail}" onclick="if(!confirm('{!contactsAboutToEmail}')){return false};"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The problem is that the string I had just confirmed in a debug log doesn't get displayed; only what it was at the beginning:

[image]

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using partial page rerenders that don't include the `<apex:commandButton>` as you build this string?

Comment: No.  actionSupports for inputCheckboxes, which call the methods that build the string (among other things).  No rerenders and the methods don't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

> No. actionSupports for inputCheckboxes, which call the methods that build the string (among other things). No rerenders and the methods don't return anything.

The [`<apex:actionSupport>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) component does not, by itself, rerender the page or any components you don't tell it to rerender.

Your `<apex:commandButton>` has, at the time of the initial page rendering, a blank value for `contactsAboutToEmail` based on the value that's initialized (if any) when the controller is created.

```
    <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!SendEmail}" onclick="if(!confirm('{!contactsAboutToEmail}')){return false};"/>
```

But this reference to the controller property isn't "dynamic", whether or not it's embedded in JavaScript. You need to rerender this component in order for it to obtain the new value of `contactsAboutToEmail` that you're building via the checkboxes that aren't shown in your posted source code.

You need to target any components whose values depend upon the value of that property in the `rerender` properties of your action support components. One easy way to do this is to wrap a region in an `<apex:outputPanel>` with an `id` attribute and rerender that attribute.